# Estimate the common center of mass of a group of objects with different densities

Tags: python

This question has received a continuous interest, has shown [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31062/). I am having trouble using the nice Python script @kuroi neko kindly updated. When running (with two or more objects with weights selected) under Blender v.3.5.1, I get the following error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 

>File "C:\Users...\twoCubes.blend\Text.001", line 90, in <module> 

> File "C:\Users...\twoCubes.blend\Text.001", line 84, in cg

> File "C:\Users\twoCubes.blend\Text.001", line 79, in cg_switch

>  File "C:\Users\twoCubes.blend\Text.001", line 15, in cg_mesh

> TypeError: Object.to_mesh(): takes at most 2 arguments, got 3
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Duplicate the objects, join them, apply the "origin to center of mass" operator, read the object's location, delete the temporary object.

Comment: Sorry, the initial version of my question was missing an important part: my objects have different densities (this should be already implemented in the script of @kuroi neko, but it's just that I can't make it run)